# Using localflavor Django form fields on Google's App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-forms

Is it possible to use the form fields from

```
django.contrib.localflavor.us.forms
```

on the Google App Engine?  Can I simply use those form fields, or do I need a form field under

```
google.appengine.ext.db.djangoforms
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to grab the folder under `django.contrib.localflavour` and import it into your app.